# How can my Cognito-based app determine which UI should be available to the logged-in user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

In a single page ReactJS app, I would like to show UI elements that control features which the current user is permitted to access, and hide elements when the current user is not permitted. The app uses Cognito via [AWS Amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify). It makes REST requests via AWS API Gateway, where IAM policies determine whether each endpoint is permitted. The way I see it, the app needs to predict which API Gateway endpoints are permitted, in order to determine which UI elements are visible. For example, when I change the policies controlling access to the back-end API, I would like to be sure that the corresponding changes happen in the front-end UI.

I noticed that Google Cloud has a [Testing Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions) feature that might be useful for this goal. The app could query which endpoints and methods are allowed for the current user. Is there a similar technique for AWS? The [IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) looks like it is not designed for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose using AWS Cognito sync store for this type of customized and ever-changing access policies: https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/#sync

This features also tries to solve some of the syncing problem with mobile devices: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html which might not be necessary for your case. I am interested to learn if there's any other recommended way to implement your described feature as well.

Thanks!